# исключение "Нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу"

Tags: c++

Я написал программу для обхода вершин графа. Однако в конструкторе графа происходит исключение:

> 0xC0000005: нарушение прав доступа при чтении по адресу 0x00000018.
>
> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Строка, на которой вызывается исключение:

```
if (map[i + width*j + 1] == 0) Edges[i + j*width].neighbors.push_back(&Edges[i + width*j + 1]);
```

Весь код:

```
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <unordered_set> 
#include <iostream>
#include<stack>
using namespace std;
class GraphEdge {
public:
    vector<GraphEdge*>neighbors;
    GraphEdge *PreviousEdge;
    int Coordinate;
    GraphEdge() { neighbors.reserve(10); }
    GraphEdge(int input) {
        Coordinate = input;
        neighbors.reserve(10);
    }
    GraphEdge(const GraphEdge &input) {
        neighbors = input.neighbors;
        Coordinate = input.Coordinate;

    }
    stack<int>CreatePath(GraphEdge* start, GraphEdge* end) {
        stack <int>Path;
        GraphEdge* current = end;
        while (current->PreviousEdge != start)
        {
            Path.push(current->Coordinate);
            current = current->PreviousEdge;
        }
        Path.push(start->Coordinate);
        return Path;
    }
};
class Graph {
public:
    vector<GraphEdge>Edges;
    int width;
    int height;
    Graph(int* map, int xI, int yI) {
        width = xI;
        height = yI;            
        for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
            for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
                Edges.push_back(*(new GraphEdge(i + j*width)));
        for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
            for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
            {
                if (i == 0)
                    ;
                else if (j == 0)
                    ;
                else if (i == width - 1)
                    ;
                else if (j == height - 1)
                    ;
                else
                {//здесь ошибка
                    if (map[i + width*j + 1] == 0) Edges[i + j*width].neighbors.push_back(&Edges[i + width*j + 1]);
                    if (map[i + width*j + -1] == 0) Edges[i + j*width].neighbors.push_back(&Edges[i + width*j - 1]);
                    if (map[i + width*(j + 1)] == 0)  Edges[i + j*width].neighbors.push_back(&Edges[i + width*(j + 1)]);
                    if (map[i + width*(j - 1)] == 0)  Edges[i + j*width].neighbors.push_back(&Edges[i + width*(j - 1)]);
                }
            }
    }
    stack<int>FindPath(int startIndex, int endIndex)
    {
        stack<int>path;
        GraphEdge* start = &Edges[startIndex];
        start->PreviousEdge = start;
        //GraphEdge end(Edges[endIndex]);
        unordered_set<int> visited;
        queue<GraphEdge*> aroundEdges;
        for (int i = 0; i < start->neighbors.size(); i++)
        {
            visited.insert(start->neighbors[i]->Coordinate);
            aroundEdges.push(start->neighbors[i]);
            start->neighbors[i]->PreviousEdge = start;
        }
        visited.insert(start->Coordinate);
        while (aroundEdges.size() != 0)
        {
            GraphEdge* current = aroundEdges.front();
            aroundEdges.pop();
            if (current == &Edges[endIndex])
            {
                path = current->CreatePath(&Edges[startIndex], &Edges[startIndex]);
                break;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < current->neighbors.size(); i++)
            {
                if (visited.count(current->neighbors[i]->Coordinate) == 0)
                {
                    visited.insert(current->neighbors[i]->Coordinate);
                    current->neighbors[i]->PreviousEdge = current;
                    aroundEdges.push(current->neighbors[i]);
                }
            }
        }


        return path;
    }

};

void main()
{
    int*map[16];
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            map[i + j * 4] = 0;
    Graph* test = new Graph(*map, 4, 4);
    stack<int> testpath = test->FindPath(5, 10);
    for (int i = 0; i < testpath.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << testpath.top();
        testpath.pop();
    }
}
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Это скорее всего, задан неправильный индекс, по нему ничего нет. Например, массив размера 10, по адресу 10 уже переполнение.

Comment: в первом цикле конструктора я создаю 16 элементов(для входных данных из примера) и заполняю ими вектор Edges. ошибка возникает при обращении к элементу вектора с индексом шесть..т.е. не должно быть пусто. так же с вектором neighbors.

Comment: А дебаггер это подтверждает?

Comment: Сделайте точку останова breakpoint и посмотрите, что в массиве.

Comment: Да, на момент выполнения строки, с которой происходит вылет в Edge 16 элементов. я никак не инициализирую в конструкторе класса GraphEdge поля PreviousEdge(ссылочный тип), может в этом проблема ? но в строке с вылетом, я никак не обращаюсь к этому полю

Comment: Чем гадать, посмотрите в breakpoing

Comment: https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2017/10/22/d2b06e46a35b3cc46f4731d6a6574e6a-full.png   .. получается ошибка в PreviousEdge?

Comment: Нет, в самом Edge.

Comment: Edges.push_back(*(new GraphEdge(i + j*width)));
Почему с *? Почему не  Edges.push_back(new GraphEdge(i + j*width));

Comment: потому что оператор new возвращает ссылку на объект, а в векторе Edges мы храним сами объекты .. или я неправильно что-то понял? без звездочки компилятор ругается: невозможно преобразовать аргумент 1 из "GraphEdge *" в "GraphEdge &&"

Comment: Так можно вектор ссылок. Хотя так тоже не запрещено.

Comment: Лучше бы с вектором ссылок работать.

Comment: Хорошо, перепишу вектор для ссылок.. а все же интересно, что не так в данной реализации

Comment: Поняла. new Graph(map, 4, 4);

Comment: ошибку дает map

Comment: Вы правы. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

int* map[16]; = это массив указателей. Надо объявить массив и передать его.

```
int map[16];
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            map[i + j * 4] = 0;
    Graph* test = new Graph(map, 4, 4);
```